# Не могу подключиться к БД PostgreSQL14. Не запускается служба PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Когда я пытаюсь подключиться через SQL Shell выходит ошибка (через pgAdmin4 также не подключается):

> psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432
> failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
> connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

В службах Windows PostgreSQL не запускается (установлена Win10).

Это решение не помогло https://stackoverflow.com/a/27568135/17655569.

Также пробовал переустановить по этой инструкции https://webkul.com/blog/postgresql-windows-installation-problem-running-post-install-step-installation-may-not-complete-correctly/. Но к сожалению, помогает только до первой перезагрузки.

Как можно решить данную проблему? Я начинаю учить язык программирования Java. Может твообще установить другую СУБД? SQLite 3 подойдет?

Вот нашел в логах:

> ВАЖНО: XX000: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\postgres.exe:
> подходящий исполняемый файл postgres не найден ПОЛОЖЕНИЕ:
> getInstallationPaths, postmaster.c:1495

Comment: Какая версия Win10 (лицензия) какой, инстолятор для установки используете? [PostgreSQL](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)

Comment: Проблема была решена. Я где-то в настройках менял кодировку postgres на cp1251. Из-за нее были конфликты и не запускалась

Answer (score 0):

если это ещё актуально, мне помогло удаление autorun (chcp 1251) в реестре.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun

Ссылка на это решение:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413979/can-not-run-postgresql-by-pg-ctl